# Mysql History Trigger Auto Increment bug or problem

Tags: mysql, trigger, auto-increment

I want to log history of a table, I created a history table and triggers for update,insert and delete operations. I do my test on realtime replication slave.

When a record inserted master's main table, trigger adds new row to history table with **last_insert_id** of **main table**. But when I add manualy add to new record main table on slave,  trigger adds new record to history table with **correct auto_increment** value.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `maintable_versioning_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `maintable`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `maintable_versions` (`version_id`,`old_version_id`, `maintable_id`, `xxx_id`, `yyy_id`, `zzz_id`, `type`)
  VALUES
    (NULL, NULL, NEW.`maintable_id`, NEW.`xxx_id`, NEW.`yyy_id`, NEW.zzz_id,'NEW');
END
```

----Table----

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `maintable_versions` (
  `version_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `old_version_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'old version id of row',
  `type` enum('NEW','UPDATE','DELETE') NOT NULL,
  `maintable_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxx_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `yyy_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `zzz_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=103243678 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `maintable_versions`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`version_id`);


ALTER TABLE `maintable_versions`
  MODIFY `version_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```